# EntityQuery with a condition on an array

Tags: 8, database

I try to list all fields where a paragraph type is referenced (to find all contents which have paragraphs of a specific type).

My problem: I do a EntityQuery on field_config entity type to find the fields. But, the condition on which paragraph_type are targeted doesn't work correctly and return all fields which can content a paragraph disregarding the type.

Here my code:

```
// Recover my paragraph_type selected in my form.
$paragraph_type = $form_state->getValue('paragraph_type');

// List all field_config which referred this paragraph_type.
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('field_config')
  ->condition('field_type', 'entity_reference_revisions')
  ->condition('settings.handler', 'default:paragraph')
  ->condition('settings.handler_settings.target_bundles', $paragraph_type, 'IN');

$field_config = $query->execute();
```

For exemple, I have a paragraph type "press_release_about" which can be add only in press release in a specific field. But for this paragraph (and all others), it's all fields which can contains a paragraph in the system which are returned.

When I inspect a field_config which referred paragraph, I can see that **settings.handler_settings.target_bundles** is an array of the paragraph types which can be add with this field. The format is:

```
[settings:protected] => Array
    (
        [handler] => 'default:paragraph'
        [handler_settings] => Array
            (
                [target_bundles] => Array
                    (
                        [1col_text] => 1col_text
                        [1col_image] => 1col_image
                        [1col_quote] => 1col_quote
                        [1_col_graphique] => 1_col_graphique
                        [2_cols_texte_media] => 2_cols_texte_media
                        [2_cols_texte_graphique] => 2_cols_texte_graphique
                        [2_cols_text] => 2_cols_text
                    )
              )
         )
```

If I remove the condition `->condition('settings.handler_settings.target_bundles', $paragraph_type, 'IN')`, this change nothing. And if I change the `IN`by `NOT IN`, I have no result.

I don't know if I don't write my condition correctly or if my error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

try to use an array instead of the value of $paragraph_type.

that would be like this :

```
->condition('settings.handler_settings.target_bundles', [$paragraph_type], 'IN')
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this cannot be achieved directly with `IN` or other default operators atm.

This will throw an error like this:

```
PHP Warning:  mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/bayer/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/Query/Condition.php on line 171
```

There is an open issue queue exactly for this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2248567

Meanwhile, if you want to achieve this somehow, then we can do something like this:

Example: Consider if the `settings.handler_settings.target_bundles` key in some `field_config` config has values like these:

```
[
  'article'=> 'article', 
  'faq' => 'faq', 
  // etc... 
]
```

Then we can use entityQuery something like this to add a condition based on these.

```php
// Recover my paragraph_type selected in my form.
$paragraph_type = $form_state->getValue('paragraph_type');

// List all field_config which referred this paragraph_type.
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('field_config')
  ->condition('field_type', 'entity_reference_revisions')
  ->condition('settings.handler', 'default:paragraph')
  // We can write some logic to make 'article' dynamically via a variable.
  ->condition('settings.handler_settings.target_bundles.article', 'article');

$field_config = $query->execute();
```

Comment: The linked issue above has a comment which I believe is the ideal solution to query a field containing an array:
`->condition('settings.handler_settings.target_bundles.*', $paragraph_type)`